# Spring MVC: Domain restriction for a single controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I know that we can use Spring security to restrict access to a controller by IP address or even I can create my custom annotation to add some custom logic for this purpose.
I need to restrict access to a controller in my application to only specific domain name ( a third party ), I checked with this third party provider for the IP ranges which I can use to configure at my end, however they want to have more freedom around IP address and would like me to create access based on the domain name.

I checked through the doc but unable to find any such use cases, Can any one help me to understand if this is possible or I need to go back to IP based access mechanism ?

Comment: IP adresses can be spoofed, headers can be added. If you want proper access restriction on something like that, consider two-way ssl handshakes with certificate pinning.  But that is something covered usually in the webserver, not in spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use Spring's CORS support for this.

ie if the domain that you expect the request is example.com you can have in your controller method the following annotation

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://example.com")
```

> This @CrossOrigin annotation enables cross-origin requests only for
>   this specific method. By default, its allows all origins, all headers,
>   the HTTP methods specified in the @RequestMapping annotation and a
>   maxAge of 30 minutes is used. You can customize this behavior by
>   specifying the value of one of the annotation attributes: origins,
>   methods, allowedHeaders, exposedHeaders, allowCredentials or maxAge.
>   In this example, we only allow http://localhost:8080 to send
>   cross-origin requests.

Have a look in the following url https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/